# CERN ROOT from Miniconda on Mac OS High Sierra: libpng conflict

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, conda, root-framework

I am trying to install Python 3, CERN ROOT and Jupyter lab from miniconda on my mac (OS High Sierra 10.13.4). I don't want to touch my working system install, which is Python2.7 with CERN ROOT on top so I'm going to make a separate environment.

This is how my $PATH looks like when I start:

/usr/local/Cellar/root/6.10.08/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/opt/X11/bin

From a fresh terminal I do:

> wget https://repo.continuum.io/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
>   bash Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh

This installs miniconda3 into /Users/urania277/miniconda3, and adds the following line to my .bash_profile

> export PATH="/Users/urania277/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"

so that when I open a new window my PATH acquires that. (As an aside, this seems to be deprecated in the new version of conda, but it doesn't affect the following).

In a new window, I then open conda, add the appropriate channels:

> conda config --add channels https://conda.anaconda.org/NLeSC

and create/install the environment I want:

> conda create --name=Root6Python3 root=6 python=3
>   ...
>   conda activate Root6Python3

After installation, I source the ROOT script to get the environment set up

> source /Users/urania277/miniconda3/envs/Root6Python3/bin/thisroot.sh

but when I try to start ROOT I get what I believe is a libpng conflict:

> (Root6Python3) jocke:~ urania277$ root 
>   dyld: Symbol not found: __cg_png_create_info_struct
>     Referenced from: /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>    Expected in: /Users/urania277/miniconda3/envs/Root6Python3/lib/libPng.dylib
>   in /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/Versions/A/ImageIO
>   Abort trap: 6

I've seen a number of variants of this error on this website but none of the recipes I have found solved my problem. Any hints?

Thanks!
Caterina

Comment: You might want to check https://root-forum.cern.ch there is usually more activity than on SO in matters of root. (Don't know if the NLeSC maintainers are checking there though)

Comment: indeed, I've done that and contacted the NLeSC mantainers as well - I was waiting for a resolution before posting here again (looks like one has to repackage the conda ROOT after some changes in ROOT itself)